# Django передаваемые параметры GET

Tags: python, django

При изучении django, мной был написан обработчик, который выбирает из базы по определенным критериям информацию, количество критериев может быть от 0 до 3, критерии необходимо передавать через `request`

```
def get_washings(request):
    washings = Washing.objects.all()
    campus = request.GET.get('campus')
    if campus is not None:
        washings = washings.filter(campus_case = campus)
    empty = request.GET.get('is_empty')
    if empty is not None:
        washings = washings.filter(is_empty = empty)
    status = request.GET.get('status')
    if status is not None:
        washings = washings.filter(status = status)
    return render(request, 'washing/washings.html', {'washings': washings})
```

Вызов данного обработчика прописан в `url.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^washing/show/$', views.get_washings, name = 'washing'),

]
```

как вариант использовалась запись

```
url(r'^washing/show/<int:campus>/<int:status>/<int:is_empty>/$', views.get_washings, name = 'washing')
```

но у меня не получается вызвать данный обработчик из браузера, т.е.
при вызове

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/washing/?campus=1&is_empty=0&status=0/

или

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/washing/1/1/1/

появляется ошибка:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/washing/?campus=1&is_empty=0&status=0/
>   Using the URLconf defined in application.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ^**debug**/ admin/ ^accounts/login/$ [name='login']
>   ^accounts/profile/$ ^washing/show/$ [name='washing'] ^washing/one/$
>   [name='one_washing'] The current path, washing/, didn't match any of
>   these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page

.

Comment: Что значит "не получается вызвать"? Компьютер выключается?

Comment: сейчас добавлю все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо поменяйте определение представления на

```
def get_washings(request, campus, status, is_empty):
```

и тогда открывайте ссылку `/washing/show/1/1/1/`. Либо измените паттерн в urls.py

```
url(r'^washing/$', views.get_washings, name = 'washing')
```

Answer (score 0):

И в первой и во второй патерне урла есть show

```
^washing/show/$
^washing/show/<int...
```

В ссылках, по которым вы проходите его уже нету.

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/washing/?campus=1&is_empty=0&status=0/
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/washing/1/1/1/

Выводы думаю излишни.

P.S файлы с урлами приняты называть urls.py и не плохо бы лучше форму сделать, чтобы куча однотипных проверок не загромождали метод [**Тык**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/).

UPD: думаю, уже сами нашли ошибку, энивэй про формы почитайте.